# ImportError: cannot import name 'GroupCall' from 'pytgcalls'

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Installed py-tgcalls module using the command

```
pip install py-tgcalls -U
```

But I am getting this error

`ImportError: cannot import name 'GroupCall' from 'pytgcalls' (C:\Users\Student\lib\site-packages\pytgcalls\__init__.py)`

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling py-tgcalls also tried to find if some file was named py-tgcalls but failed to find any.

Comment: Please mention version of  `py-tgcalls` after installation or upgradation

Comment: @BhavyaParikh it did't work. Can you please explain what you want to say, I might be misinterpreting you.

Comment: I dont know about much this library but what you are importing and which module you have installed both are different so you should install `pip install pytgcalls` this command and you can find [docs](https://pypi.org/project/pytgcalls/) where they have used `from pytgcalls import GroupCall`

Comment: Yes, I tried installing pytgcalls `pip install pytgcalls` instead but the terminal gave an error `Conflicting Dependencies` and asked to remove version specification which I didn't already do I just used `pip install pytgcalls`

Next TIme I used `pip install pytgcalls==0.0.23` but the terminal returned an error again,`ERROR: No matching distribution found for tgcalls==0.0.13`

@BhavyaParikh

Comment: Create separate environment with suitable python version and then install `pytgcalls` to avoid this kind of errors!